# Bootstrap 3 ads responsive

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-ads-api

I have implemented Bootstrap 3 for a project. I used responsive mode to modify the content using media query. I want to do the same thing for my Google ads.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 well" id="add1"">

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-1823432637478832"
 data-ad-slot="6148460992"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google adsense does not support responsive ads, there is still beta release from google

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```